# cannot find button element, selenium, python

Tags: python, selenium, web

Already try by xpath, class_name, name, tag_name, everything! but cannot find this element, the html code llok like this.

```
<button class ="btn btn-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" name="submitBtn">Crear cuenta</button>
```

I don't know why  can't find the element, here an example of my code triying to find the element

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/footer/button").click()
```

Comment: Can you share the site you are trying to read the element?

Comment: Is it inside an iframe?

Comment: sharing more html code will help us to give you some tip about your problem; can be a invalid xpath also

Comment: sure dani https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=es

Comment: im not sure if is inside and iframe but i think its is, already try self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))  to enter the iframe but still cannot find the elemnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the web site you passed has a load screen the element you want to grab is not available to interaction.

For that you can use the selenium web driver Expected Conditions.

Here an use example on how to use.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
...
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "dtListaEntidade")))
# do your stuff with elements
```

Im my example the element I want to grab is the `dtListaEntidade`.

1. I'm telling the `webdriver` to wait the present of that element for 
   10 ms
2. check if the element is available
3. do 1. again

This waits up to 10 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException unless it finds the element to return within 10 seconds.

WebDriverWait by default calls the ExpectedCondition every 500 milliseconds until it returns successfully.

Here is  the documentation from [selenium docs waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)